# Is it an acceptable practice to store guest user data in cookies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, system-design

I'm working on a Pomodoro-style application for fun in my free time (as a side-project to help with internships) and the application has a to-do list feature as well as saving session analytics for data visualization. I intend to create a complete backend for users to authenticate with, however, I don't want to force users to create an account to save this data. As in, I want them to be able to persist to-do items in the browser and when they decide to create an account that data will be transferred to the backend.

Initially, my plan was to store this guest user data in the backend with a userId stored in a cookie. So, this guest user data would be saved in a guest database which could be accessed without authentication with that userId. Then, if they create an account, the guest data would be transferred to the authenticated database. However, I feel like this is over-engineering (please feel free to correct me).

My question is: **is it ok to store all of this user data in cookies (not send it to a database at all)?** And then when the user decides to create an account the data stored in the cookies is sent to the database.

Comment: For serverless PWA application it is ok to store data in browser. However, there is several type of storages provided by most browsers: localStorage, cookies, indexedb. 
Cookies is simple key-value pair, but compare to other storages, their have very specific properties (browser send cookies to server with the same domain with every request).
For to-do items I recommend you to use localStorage (easy implementation) or indexedb (hard implementation).

Comment: Thank you, I think I might go with indexedb as this is the first time I've heard of it and it sounds like a good challenge. I've used localStorage and cookies in the past.